# Draggable Javascript Treeview

Tags: javascript

I need to develop a drag-able and editable tree view. Any javascript components to use?

I'm using jQuery so it could be a jQuery add-in too. I'll use the tree view for display and edit sitemap structure.

And lastly, it'll be great if the component supports JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're programming in .NET and willing to pay, [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) has some good server controls that are pretty easy to use, and are well supported.  Check out the demos for [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and [TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).  They come packaged as server controls with fully fleshed out server and client side apis.  I believe support JSON as well.  If you pay for the package, you get a ton of other useful server controls as well.

Comment: Yes I'm using .Net; but Telerik's TreeView is too slow and reordering its items are relatively hard. Telerik is on my list too, but I hope to find better one.

Comment: Well, ok.  I'm not sure you'll find anything easier to use or faster than Telerik out there, but good luck!